# Kibana not using existing .kibana index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I have 2 AWS EC2 instances. One for Elasticsearch (ES) and one for Kibana.
I'm trying to backup all the data from ES to AWS S3 and then restore it when creating a new instance.

The way I'm doing it is this:

1. Terminate Kibana instance
2. Backup ES data with curator
3. Terminate ES instance
4. Startup new ES instance and restore data with curator
5. Startup new Kibana instance

The problem is that even though the restoration works (I can see the indices restored in ES including a .kibana_1 index that has an alias to .kibana), when Kibana starts up it doesn't use the existing .kibana_1 index but creates a new one (e.g.: .kibana_2)

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

(I'm using the 7.0.1 version of both services and curator 5.7.6)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the index is just a file on the OS using a GUID as the file name. So when you restore these files will be recreated nulifying all the objects referring to these indices. The only way to fix this is to edit the objects by going to saved objects and modify the index used with the latest GUID key.
To navigate to the object go to Management and then Saved Objects. Find the object in question. Click on the three dots, select inpect.
Normally this is a problem for visualisations so what I do is edit the Reference portion and past in the new GUID as the value of "id"
See the example below.

```
[
  {
    "name": "kibanaSavedObjectMeta.searchSourceJSON.index",
    "id": "71eacc40-fa33-11e9-be5b-a960e3c83f4d",
    "type": "index-pattern"
  },
  {
    "name": "kibanaSavedObjectMeta.searchSourceJSON.filter[0].meta.index",
    "id": "71eacc40-fa33-11e9-be5b-a960e3c83f4d",
    "type": "index-pattern"
  }
]
```

I know this does not fully answer your question but does give solution to fix issue after restore.
btw.
I am using Kibana 7.4.0

If you have allot of visualisations then this could become a big job. Maybe someone else knwows how to bulk edit these configs externally.